# Incrementing value in Oracle query

Tags: oracle

I have two columns in a table like below:

[image]

And I need data like this:

[image]

New column which should have `ID||object||rownum` for each code...i.e. for girl it should start incrementing from one and then for boy also rownum should start to increment by 1 as shown above.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
 select id||object|| row_number() over (partition by  code order by ID) from table;
```